# mapshot() produces Error in (function (url = NULL, file = "webshot.png", vwidth = 992, vheight = 744, : webshot.js returned failure value: 1

Tags: r

I am creating a Report with R Markdown and a part of it is based on maps that I create with leaflet. Then I use mapshot to create a jpg and save the map. So that I can load and show the jpg in the Report.

So far this worked fine, but since my last R update (Version 4.2.0) mapshot creates an Error. And unfortunately I can hardly find any support on this error online. That's why I have created this account and this reproducible example:

```
library("leaflet")
library("mapview")

m <- leaflet() %>%
  addTiles() %>%  # Add default OpenStreetMap map tiles
  addMarkers(lng=174.768, lat=-36.852, popup="The birthplace of R")
m 
mapshot(m, file = "C:/Rplot2.jpg")
```

This is the error I get:

```
Could not load  c:%5CUsers%5CVedi%5CAppData%5CLocal%5CTemp%5CRtmpqcG5qY%5Cfile36844d44770d.html
Error in (function (url = NULL, file = "webshot.png", vwidth = 992, vheight = 744,  : 
  webshot.js returned failure value: 1
```

I am happy about any helpful ideas to solve this problem!

Answer (score 1):

It is not an answer. I don't have enough credits to add a comment so I am putting my comments here. I had the same error message and posted an issue to the mapview github (https://github.com/r-spatial/mapview/issues/427) with a reference to your question.